# Java- Create two different trees in the same database class using generic dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, tree

How  do I implement `binary search tree methods` for two different trees stored as a dictionary in the same database class?
I already made my generic dictionary interface and created the methods for a binary search tree(insert, delete, find) that works for the data stored as a dictionary in a binary search tree.
My plan is to create a student database that stores the students name in the Dictionary implemented as a String and the student ID number in the Dictionary implemented as a integer. I am confused on how to use my `BST` methods for two different trees in the same database class for both dictionary types.

Comment: So you'd just put 2 tree objects in your main DB class, right?

Comment: but how will i assign the BST method while making sure it is in the assigned dictionary?

Comment: Please give us code, otherwise this is way too nebulous to even understand. Thanks